# Substring in string in bash?

Tags: bash, sed

What is the equivalent of the python statement in bash:

```
if "mystr" in "a long string with mystring in it":
    print("found string")
```

The offset in number of characters can NOT be relied on to be constant, so I don't think I can get `cut` to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use wildcard matching. For bash specifically:

```
if [[ $longstring == *mystr* ]]; then

if [[ $longstring == *"my string"* ]]; then

if [[ $longstring == *"$matchstr"* ]]; then
```

In the `[[` operator, the left-side is expanded literally (that is, without the need to double-quote), while the unquoted parts of the right-side are treated like wildcards – basically the same quoting rules as  in a `case` statement.

It's possible to use POSIX regex match as well:

```
if [[ $longstring =~ mystr ]]; then

if [[ $longstring =~ "my string" ]]; then

if [[ $longstring =~ "$matchstr" ]]; then
```

Again, the quoted parts of the right-side are matched literally while unquoted parts are matched as regex operators.

---

If you require *sh* compatibility:

```
case $longstring in
    *mystr*)
        echo yes;;
    *"$matchstr"*)
        echo yes again!;;
    *)
        echo no;;
esac
```

Alternatively, if you're into abusing the language:

```
if case $longstring in
    *mystr*) true;;
    *"$matchstr"*) true;;
    *) false;;
esac; then
    ...
fi
```

*(This if/case/esac/then form is actually useful in some situations, like when making an incremental whitelist/blacklist.)*

Shorter version:

```
if ! case $longstring in *"$matchstr"*) !; esac; then
    echo "It matched!"
fi
```

---

Many sh scripts use `expr` but it's not a shell built-in, therefore a bit slower:

```
if expr match "$longstring" ".*mystr"; then
    ...
fi
```

In this case (as expr cannot see differences in quoting) the entire "match" parameter is interpreted as an anchored regex (like grep but always with a `^` prepended). Therefore be careful when passing a variable as the match.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
#! /bin/bash

X=`echo "a long string with mystring in it" | grep "mystr" | wc -l`
if [ $X -gt 0 ]
then
        echo "found string";
fi
```

The idea here being that "echo" sets up the string, grep looks for the substring in the string passed to it, and wc -l returns the number of lines the string was found in - so either 0 or 1.

Comment: found this as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/299710/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-substring-of-another-in-bash

Comment: I was just working on something like that for a more sophisticated answer - I have now come up with the following 1 liner (which is arguably closer to what you wanted) :  echo "a long string with mystring in it" | grep -q "mystr" &&  echo "found string"  - but your way is more efficient.

Comment: ahhhh!  grep returns 0 if match found.  much more readable

Comment: Yes, that means you can simplify it to `if echo ... | grep -q ...; then`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bash` parameter expansion:

```
if [ "${TestString/$SearchString/}" == "$TestString" ]; then echo Found; fi
```

or if you want a Bourne-compatible expression:

```
if [ "${TestString#*$SearchString}" == "$TestString" ]; then echo Found; fi
```

`$SearchString` can be a literal: it can contain spaces, whether a literal or variable, and a variable can contain `}`, but in a literal it must be escaped as `\}`. In the first form, the same consideration also applies to `/`.